# Remove blank lines from a text file

Tags: php, file

I have a text file that has some blank lines in it. Meaning lines that have nothing on them and are just taking up space.

It looks like this:

```
The

quick
brown

fox jumped over
the

lazy dog
```

and I need it to look like this:

```
The
quick
brown
fox jumped over
the
lazy dog
```

How can I remove those blank lines and take only the lines with the content and write them to a new file?

Here is what I know how to do:

```
$file = fopen('newFile.txt', 'w');
$lines = fopen('tagged.txt');
foreach($lines as $line){
    /* check contents of $line. If it is nothing or just a \n then ignore it.
    else, then write it using fwrite($file, $line."\n");*/
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant `file('tagged.txt')` instead?

Comment: str_replace() double line break

Comment: You could use `sed`: `sed -e '/^$/d' tagged.txt > newFile.txt`.

Comment: @Jon is `file()` more proper than `fopen()` ?

Comment: @JayGatz: They do different things.

Comment: @Jon Could you please quickly explain to me the difference.

Comment: @JayGatz: Reading the manual on the two functions will explain it much better than I can.

Comment: @Jon Okay, I'll read up on both of them. Thank you for letting me know that they are different!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the file is not too large:

```
file_put_contents('newFile.txt',
                  implode('', file('tagged.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES)));
```

Comment: It is long, 200k, lines, but just text so it is not that large.

Comment: The [php documentation on file_put_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php): "_You can also specify the data parameter as a single dimension array. This is equivalent to file_put_contents($filename, implode('', $array))._", so this can even be shorter by just leaving out the call to impode().

Comment: This didn't work for me. FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES don't do any magic.

Answer (score 4):

```
file_put_contents('newFile.txt',
    preg_replace(
        '~[\r\n]+~',
        "\r\n",
        trim(file_get_contents('tagged.txt'))
    )
);
```

I like `\r\n` :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a foreach-based solution to just filter out empty lines (without writing to a file):

```
$lines = file('in.txt');
foreach ($lines as $k => $v) {
    if (!trim($v))
        unset($lines[$k]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the whole thing in one go:

```
file_put_contents('newFile.txt',
    preg_replace(
        '/\R+/',
        "\n",
        file_get_contents('tagged.txt')
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
file_put_contents(
  "new_file.txt",
  implode(
    "", 
    array_filter(
      file("old_file.txt")
    ))
);
```

This code first reads the file to an array (`file()`), filters out the empty elements (`array_filter`) then writes them to a new file. The implode delimiter is empty, as `file` leaves the `\n` characters at the end of each line.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($lines as $line) {
    if ($line!=='') $file.write($line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with strpos. search for \n. if returned value is 0 you unset line